# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404”

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, iis, cors

I am unable to make the POST calls from angular application, IIS server is rejecting the request with “***Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404***”,I know there are a lot of questions like this, but none I've seen have fixed my issue

I already have the following in my web.config and still see the issue?I have enabled CORS aswell, and GET requests work.can anyone give pointers are how to debug this issue?

```
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

UPDATE:

```
    [Route("api/SoftwareProduct/GetBuildNotes")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ResponseObject GetBuildNotes([FromBody] BuildNotes_ip BuildNotes)
    {
        ResponseObject response = new ResponseObject();
        try
        {
            response.status = 200;
            response.data = SPS.GetBuildNotes(BuildNotes);
            if (BuildNotes.IsEdit)
                response.message = "Inserted Data successfully.";
            else
                response.message = "Fetched Data successfully.";
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            response.status = 200;
            response.data = null;
            response.message = e.Message;
            return response;
        }

    }
```

Error:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this is a cors issue. Make sure that your backend server is accepting not only the `POST` request but also an `OPTIONS` request for the same endpoint url. The `OPTIONS` request should just return with the success 200 code

Comment: Anis - can you please expand on  `accepting OPTIONS request` ?how and where to add this?

Comment: you have a server to which you are sending a `POST` request. On that server you probably have something like "when a user hits endpoint `/abc` with request type `POST` return something". You also need something that says "when a user hits endpoint `/abc` with request type `OPTIONS` return `200 OK`"

Comment: what you said is very vague..no specifics...couldn't translate into anything implementable

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the **CORS** issue is misleading in that it might be a different exception but it's still shown. I'd suggest the following just as a pointer: 
I assume  you're using Chrome on windows. Run the command below to open Chrome with **Websecurity(including CORS)** disabled. Make sure to close any instance of Chrome before running this command.

Go to Windows Icon > Run:

> chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session"
>   --disable-web-security

Then run the app once more, and let us know the outcome. Also, it'll be helpful if you shared your **http post** code and the signature of your API Controller method, including the **route**.

Comment: Felix - still have this issue even after trying this...,updated my question with the latest code

Comment: Hi @dot_net I saw the update and the Web API snippet looks okay. Can you also update with the AngularJS snippet? Maybe the way you're binding the *BuildNotes* object is the issue. The problem is that the *Route* is not visible to the client(AngularJs).